# Macro definition change from newcommand to NewDocumentCommand produces error for empty lines in beamer slides

Tags: beamer, xparse

for slides I defined my own frame command. Now I want to change from a definition with `\newcommand` to `\NewDocumentCommand`. But empty line(s) in the `\xframe` create an error. I could replace all empty lines by `%` and then it works properly.

Since I have several hundered of slides by now, I would prefer not to touch the slide content, but to improve the definition of `\xframe`, if possible.

Thanks Sigbert

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\xframe}{om}{%
\frame{\frametitle{#1}#2}%
}

\newcommand{\myframe}[2][]{%
\frame{\frametitle{#1}#2}%  
}

\begin{document}
\myframe[Test - myframe]{

Line 1
}

% if under \xframe a % is inserted instead of the empty line the MWE works
\xframe[Test - xframe]{

Line 1
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Precede the `m` in the parameter specification by a `+`. The error you get is intentional. So, write `\NewDocumentCommand{\xframe}{o+m}{`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `beamer` was released (several years ago), it used

```
\frame{<contents>}
```

but Till Tantau realized that this syntax is bad, because it requires contortions when a frame needs to be processed with verbatim material, but not only, so the syntax changed to

```
\begin{frame}
...
\end{frame}
```

and options can be specified to `\begin{frame}`. The command `\frame` behaves as the old one, but is deprecated.

You're trying to go back to the old syntax (and also use it). Don't, for your own sake.

Anyway, if you insist on this, you need two modifications: one is to use `+m` for the mandatory argument, so blank lines are allowed; the other is in the management of the optional argument: you surely don't want -NoValue-` as the frame title if you don't specify an optional argument.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\NewDocumentCommand{\xframe}{o+m}{%
  \begin{frame}
  \IfValueT{#1}{\frametitle{#1}}
  #2
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\xframe[Test - xframe]{

Line 1

Line 2

}

\xframe{No title here}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I added a theme to show the title (or the missing one).

Comment: Well, my slides date back at least till 2013 ;) But I will update now to \begin{frame}...\end{frame}. The -NoValue- problem appears only in the MWE, my real macro handles this case, but this was not important for my problem. Thanks to all for your help